# PHP MySQL Login app that will check the username and password from MySQL server In a Local Network

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-wifi

I'm creating  Login App that will check the username and password from MySQL server  In a Local Network, I've successfully logged in from a android Emulator to a MySQL Database .I've used PHP script for the validation of the User.

**The Problem is that ,I'm Unable to Login From Android device to the  MySQL Database. I made a Local Network in My home and Dumped the PHP scripts in The Server. But it not able to Login.**

This Code is for connecting to the MySQL database

```
<?php
$db_name="user_details";
$mysql_username="root";
$mysql_password="";
$server_name="localhost";
$conn=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);

?>
```

This Code is for Validating the User

```
<?php
require "user_conn.php";
$user_name=$_POST["username"];
$user_pass=$_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry="select * from user where username like '$user_name' and      password like '$user_pass';";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
echo "Login success";
}
else
{
echo "Login  not success";
}
?>
```

These are the Java File of Android Code

**Login.java**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;

     public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button bLogin;
    EditText etUser , etPass;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etuser);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpass);
        bLogin = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.btlogin);

    }
    public void login(View view){

        String u=etUser.getText().toString();
        String p=etPass.getText().toString();
        String l="login";
        Background bg=new Background(this);

        bg.execute(l,u,p);


    }

   }
```

**Background.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class Background extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {

AlertDialog a;
Context context;

public Background(Context ct) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    context=ct;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    a=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    a.setTitle("Login Status");

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    a.setMessage(result);
    a.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String type=params[0];
    String login_url="http://10.0.2.2/login.php";

    if(type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String username=params[1];
            String password=params[2];
            URL u=new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection http=(HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream out=http.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bf= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out,"UTF-8"));
            String post_data=URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bf.write(post_data);
            bf.flush();
            bf.close();
            out.close();
            InputStream in=http.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                result+=line;
            }
            bf.close();
            in.close();
            http.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    package="com.example.login"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Background"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I don't think we consider questions regarding PHPs mysql_ API any longer

Comment: First check the response of your server code from the rest client (ex: Postman) or dummy form. So you can be assured that there is no problem with the PHP Code

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.